# Vertical and Horizontal Flexbox Containter Allign

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to place my both divs that are in the flexbox container in the middle of the screen. 
I tried with margin top and things like that, but I want them just in the middle of the page.

```
.flexbox-container
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    flex-direction: row
    flex-wrap: wrap
    min-height: 100%
    align-self: center

.flexbox-item
    width: 500px
    margin: 100px 60px
    background-color: white

.flexbox-item-1
    min-height: 500px


.flexbox-item-2
    min-height: 500px
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I give HTML and Body tags a "height: 100%" and perfect, placed in the middle of the screen!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just missing `align-items` in the container.

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I just solved giving html and body tags a height of 100%, and then worked perfectly with the code from above. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use align-items.

```
.flexbox-container
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    flex-direction: row
    flex-wrap: wrap
    min-height: 100%
    align-self: center
    align-items:center

.flexbox-item
    width: 500px
    margin: 100px 60px
    background-color: white

.flexbox-item-1
    min-height: 500px


.flexbox-item-2
    min-height: 500px
```

Comment: I just solved giving html and body tags a height of 100%, and then worked perfectly with the code from above. Thanks a lot for your help!